# Div needs to stretch to contain the inner divs

Tags: css, layout, html, containers

I've been digging around in here and none of what I've tried yet has worked.  I have a page where the containing div will not stretch to the bottom of the page when the content gets too long.  I am almost sure the problem has to do with the div soup that was handed to me.

http://www.edjetest11.com/supremeshowsupply.com/products.php?catid=1&subcatid=1

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: wich one is the div in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style for `#box_inside` has a height set, which keeps it from expanding. If you remove that, it will expand to contain its children, and the outer divs will also expand.

Now your problem is that the background image is made to fit that exact size...